# How does SQLite search for a specific table in a database?

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

I'm new in programming still learning basics, I made one android app still missing a lot of basic functionalities, it is app where I save how many hours I work each day, I'm working a job where each day is different every day I start and finish on different hours, I'm using SQLite to save those hours and some other things in that app and like I said I'm new and my question is when I create new table in database does that table get reference, so when I later want something from specific table how does SQLite system search for that specific table is that table have reference and when I 'call' for that table system instantly access it or it searches thought database for that table? And same question for MySql. Thank you, have a nice day.

Comment: I don’t understand your question. If your app is storing data in a table, you can get the data from the table. What do you mean by reference? Tables have names and that’s how you address them. I think you should find a suitable tutorial to databases, SQLite and how it’s used in Android.

Comment: If you're using SQLite, why have you tagged SQL Server and MySQL, and not tagged SQLite? :)

Comment: @Larnu I didn't found SQLite, only those what I've linked.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen My question is how system search for specific table in database, if I have 10000 tables doe's he search for one I need or he already know where it is that table so I can access that data in that table. By reference I ment address where table is stored.

Comment: With a name, you call tables with names, you set that name when you create the table, the database has constraints that dont allow tables with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

When the SQLite library has opened a database file, it stores table information in a hash table, so accesses happen in constant time.